# What configuration entry removes the "Tools->Connect to Database" menu in the Visual Studio 2012 isolated shell

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need to remove the "Tools->Connect to Database" menu in the Visual Studio 2012 isolated shell. According to MS, I need to have this entry in the "pkgundef" file.

```
// Visual Studio Explorers and Designers Package
// This package is responsible for server explorer and "Tools->Connect to Server" and     "Tools->Connect to Database" commands.
[$RootKey$\Packages\{8D8529D3-625D-4496-8354-3DAD630ECC1B}]
```

This removes "Tools->Connect to Server" but not "Tools->Connect to Database".

Comment: aclear... probably because he doesn't need to connect to a database with his application he is building?

I'm also running into this problem.... if i figure anything out ill try to come back here.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138579.aspx

This is microsoft's help for removing stuff from the isolated shell..

The example they give happens to be the one in question...

> For example, to remove the Connect to Database and Connect to Server
>   commands on the Tools menu, you can uncomment the line
>
> ```
>         [$RootKey$\Packages\{8D8529D3-625D-4496-8354-3DAD630ECC1B}]
> ```
>
> in the application's .pkgundef file.

But clearly it doesn't work.

**EDIT:** I found this on a different fourm!

```
// Server Explorer

[$RootKey$\Packages\{198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}]
```

I have no idea where it came from, but it seems to work.